# Prometheus - query for the latest available metrics, irregardless of how old it is

Tags: prometheus

I've got a VM that is up for some hours a day (usually), performs some jobs and reports their statuses with values being either `0` or `1`. I want to query on the latest available values of these jobs - obviously when the VM goes down, new metrics are not ingested, but I do not care about that.

So the question is: how can I query for the latest value of the particular metric that Prometheus ingested, even if it was a long time ago?

Considering that the metric can be either `0` or `1` and the VM usually reports metrics at least daily, I could for example go with something along the lines of `min_over_time(some_job[24h])!=1`, but I'm not 100% satisfied with that, as this query assumes that the metric was reported in the past 24h (which may not always be the case) and also would not care if the metric's value flapped between `0` and `1` in the past day.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use case for the pushgateway, which is intended for cluster-level batch jobs like these. Have your batch job push the value just before it terminates.

I would suggest pushing the timestamp at which it last succeeded rather than a 0/1. That makes it easier to alert on as you can do `time() - some_job_last_success_seconds > 86400`.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to set up something extra, neverthelss the pushgateway looks like something I could use. Thanks for the hint. Regarding `time() - some_job_last_success_seconds > 86400` - as mentioned before, this approach and similar are far from perfect for me. Still, this brings me an idea `IF some_job_last_success_seconds < some_job_last_fail_seconds THEN alert`. Will have to think it through. Appreciate your ideas!